# Is there any way to do a safe intent to camera for all level apis?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-4.2-jelly-bean

From Froyo to Ice Cream Sandwich this is the way:

```
Intent intent = new
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpg");
tempUriCameraDeviceNotSuported = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
tempUriCameraDeviceNotSuported);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But for Jelly Bean it doesn't work, you must do something like this:

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(
MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
```

I'm not sure if this bug happens only in jelly bean, or it also depends on the hardware model. Google doesn't tell a word about this issue (why? why?). Someone knows where can I find a list with all devices and their right camera implementation? Someone knows the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check for the OS version:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "test.jpg");
        tempUriCameraDeviceNotSuported = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                tempUriCameraDeviceNotSuported);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Comment: thanks but is it really the best solution? do all devices that have jelly support the same implementation? isn't it a hardware issue too?

Comment: I am not sure if its hardware issue. You can also use a try and catch. and try both of the implementation so nothing can go wrong.

Comment: But how could you do that? I mean when the intent is done -when the  code is on onActivityReult, you can't do nothing. It's imposible to turn back to the previous intent and then try the other way, isn't it?

Comment: You can don't set your result as OK and use the other implemation if it crashes. Of course this is not a good thing. But its a workaround if the device fails to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

> from Frojo to Icre cream this is the way

Please understand that what you are doing with your code is asking a random app to take a picture for you. That random app may be:

- the AOSP Camera app, or
- the device manufacturer's replacement camera app, or
- a camera app that the user installed, or
- anything else that elects to support `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` that happens to reside on the device

> But for jelly bean it doesn't work

Talented programmers would have explained what "it doesn't work" means.

> I'm not sure if this bug happens only in jelly bean

Talented programmers would have explained what "the bug" is.

Beyond that, Android itself has little, if anything, to do with it. The bug, most likely, is in whatever camera app you used on that "jelly bean" device.

> Google doesn't tell a word about this issue (why?,why?).

Talented programmers would have explained what "the issue" is in greater detail than "it doesn't work".

> Someone knows where can I find a list with all devices and their right camera implementation?

There are over 1,000 Android devices. I feel reasonably confident that there are over 1,000 apps on the Play Store and elsewhere that are "camera apps" or otherwise support `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. That means that there is in excess of 1,000,000 combinations of device and app for your list. You are welcome to develop such a list yourself.

If you feel that `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is unreliable for your case, you are welcome to take a picture yourself using `android.hardware.Camera`.

Also, FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content), which uses much the same code as is in your first code snippet, works fine on a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.1 and a Nexus S running Android 4.1.2, both of which are "jelly bean".

Answer (score 0):

Check my example, actually it works on 2.3.3 and 4.1 and 4.2 Give it a try!

[GalleryCameraDemo in Github](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/GalleryCameraDemo)