# ImageView not showing captured photo android

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I am new in android development. I have been trying to access the camera, capture a photo, and then return to my activity and show it on an ImageView.

Here is the code of my activity (very simple, it just do that)

```
public class Profile extends Activity  {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1337;
    private ImageView imagePhoto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        imagePhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
        ImageView photoButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.camera);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if( requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
        {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? I search and try so many codes. When I click in the button, the camera shows up, I take a photo, and then I return to the activity but the thumbnail of the photo is not showing in the ImageView "imagePhoto".

Here is the layout for the imagePhoto:

```
 <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imagePhoto"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
         android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/camera"
         android:src="@drawable/add_photo" /> `/* It has another photo, because I was trying to see if it changes */
```

And this is in my manifest also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

I tried so many codes! Thanks in advance. I'm using a Samsung device.

Comment: What's the problem specifically? Is the retrieved bitmap null?

Comment: @valbertos The problem is that the thumbnail is not showing the image I took. How can I now if bitmap is null?

Comment: Use your IDE or print a result based on a conditional, like this: if (thumbnail == null){Log.d("bitmap", "Bitmap is null!")}

Comment: I put that, and nothing shows in the console. @valbertos

Comment: So, the Bitmap is not null :) Try to remove the drawable set in the XML, it could be overlapping the Bitmap.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't know what else to do. I'm sure my code is fine!

Comment: Post your xml file completely. i'm going to test your code.

Comment: try to use imagePhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail); instead of   ImageView image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

Comment: Guys, it seems that the problem is that I was using Samsung S2. I tried with a SAmsung s4 and it works, whats the problem? @valbertos

Comment: I don't know xD I've tried your code with a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini and it works fine. Some time ago I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382720/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-safe-intent-to-camera-for-all-level-apis) a question that could be related .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code Looks Fine but i want to share mine as it is working for me

This code will also create a folder in your memory and save the image there

here is the code

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   ImageView image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
        // create external folder
        createFolder();
          Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
          startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888); 

    }
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
            if (requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  


         Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            image.setImageBitmap(photo );

                    // to create a random image file name
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 10000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";

                String filePath = "/sdcard/PictureFolder/"+fname;
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

                //choose another format if PNG doesn't suit you
                photo.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

                try {
                    bos.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    bos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }  
        } 

      public void createFolder()
      {
          String RootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                  + File.separator + "PictureFolder";
          File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
          RootFile.mkdir();
      }
}
```

and only i add this permission

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Your can create a new project and try this.. i hope it helps you

Comment: This code doesn't work. The app crashes when it tries to return to the activity. @SoftCoder

Comment: where is the error... logcat line? ...get me the line where the app crashes ?

Comment: i am using samsung galaxy grand neo and it works fine with this code

Comment: OK, I was using Samsung S2 and it doesnt work. But I use Samsung S4 mini and it does! What about this?!

Comment: Thats Something new :O .. ok do you get the line where the error is ?

Comment: The problem is that there is no error! It just dont show the image